# indexPath of filtered tableView

Tags: ios, core-data, uisearchbar, segue, magicalrecord

In my project I use core data with magical record.

My search bar works perfectly, but after a search If I tap on the first row of my tableview I get the detail view of the table not filtered:

so if I have 3 object named A, B, C and I search C, in my table I see only C but if i tap I get the detail view of A.

So I'm try to write a method to get the correct indexPath:

```
   -(NSIndexPath*)giveMeSearchedObject:(UISearchBar*)searchBar showInRow: (int) row
{
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nome CONTAINS [cd] %@", searchBar];
    NSArray *arra = [Ricetta MR_findAllSortedBy:@"nome" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate];
    Ricetta*ctn = arra[row];

    NSIndexPath* correctPath =arra[row];

return correctPath;

}
```

but when I call this method in the prepareForSegue to set the indexPath I can't figure out what write after "showInRow:":

```
if (searching == YES) {

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc]init];

  indexPath = [[DataManager sharedClass]giveMeSearchedObject:self.mySearchBar.text showInRow:???;


 DetailViewController*dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    dvc.indice =indexPath.row;
```

So, maybe the method isn't correct.

somebody could help me?

**UPDATE**

```
@interface
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@end
@implementation

@synthesize fetchedResultsController;


 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

    if (searching == YES) {

                UITableViewCell*cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
                NSIndexPath*indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
                Ricetta*ricetta = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                DetailViewController*dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
                dvc.indice =indexPath.row;
```

Comment: is there any unique identifier in your Array?

Comment: @Sunny yes, of course

Comment: get the original index value based on that unique identifier  and the current selected cell(indexpath.row).

Comment: @Sonny sorry but I'm new to programming. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

showInRow accepts an int so use

```
indexPath.row
```

Comment: I tried, but crash. I suppose that I can't use "indexPath" to define "indexPath"

Comment: Well you are running that from prepareForSegue so you need to make a reference to your current indexPath, don't use it exactly how I wrote it. Create a property to hold the current selectedIndex then use that. The row of that index is what you will filter your array with to grab the appropriate object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. Can you post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many issues. For example, your method `giveMeSearchedObject` should return an index path, but instead returns a `Ricetta`. Best just forget about it.

The trouble with 3rd party frameworks that are supposed to make it "easier" for "beginners" is that they are usually badly documented. Often, they add little in terms of simplification or abstraction - this includes MR. In your case you gain absolutely nothing by not using a plain vanilla `NSFetchedResultsController` which you can update with your search term.

If you are using storyboard and catch the cell selection in `prepareForSegue` you have to get to the managed object via the `sender` which is a table view cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; 
Ricetta *ricetta = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: tried your way, but doesn't work. Do I wrong something?(see UPDATE please)

Comment: PS. I know that MR isn't documented enough, but when you find your way with MR, everything is more easy.

Comment: Yes sure this code does not work. Maybe there are still some conceptional challenges... Give your detail view controller a property with the `Ricetta` entity. It should not know anything about the data, just what it needs to know to display the recipe. It is called "[encapsulation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooObjectModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH5-SW10)".